# How to filter Google Drive API v3 mimeType?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types

I wrote a script that uses DriveApp to read Google Drive, SpreadsheetApp to log data in Sheets, and Google Drive API v3  + service account + OAuth to make changes on behalf of G Suite users.

It would be nice to search Google Drive from the target user perspective (calling Google Drive API v3) instead of the account running the script (calling DriveApp). I can't get the filter to work.

The query is built with parent folder keys, `mimeType =` or `mimeType !=` for folders, and is passed into the function. The format is:

```
var query = "('GoogleDriveFolderKey01' in parents or 'GoogleDriveFolderKey02' in parents) and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

The DriveApp function uses:

```
files = Drive.Files.list({
  q: query,
  maxResults: 100,
  pageToken: pageToken
});
```

The Google Drive API v3 function uses:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'
var options = {
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'method'     : 'get',
  'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'corpora'    : 'domain',
  'q'          : query,
  'spaces'     : 'drive',
  'pageSize'   : 100,
  'pageToken'  : pageToken
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

var resultParsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
files = resultParsed.files
pageToken = resultParsed.pageToken
```

The results with DriveApp are as expected, but Google Drive API v3 results in:

```
"files": [
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "01abc123_etc",
  "name": "Something something (2021-04-15).pdf",
  "mimeType": "application/pdf"
},
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "02ABC4321-qwertyuiop",
  "name": "Super Special Worksheet",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
},
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": "whatever",
  "name": "Copy of V1",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
},
...
```

Any ideas?

### Edit:

Thank you! The problem seems to be 'corpus' and 'space'. I have used to following in Google AppsScript:

```
var options = {
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'method'     : 'get',
  'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'pageSize'   : 100
};
url += '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);
if ( pageToken.length > 0 ) url += '&pageToken=' + pageToken;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: Just an off-topic question: Why aren't you using `ScriptApp` to get the `token`?

Comment: So, after a bit of RTFM, I think some background is needed. For each top-level folder in the company Google Drive, I've assigned a "server" account that should own the files, in order to enforce sharing requirements. Account A runs the script, and for every file that server account B should own, it generates an OAuth token and transfers file ownership from user account C to server account B. As far as I can tell, ScriptApp can't make changes on behalf of other users. Smart users have figured out that the file ownership is only transferred if server account A or B have the file shared w/them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- At the method of "Files: list" in Drive API v3, the values of `corpora, q, space, pageSize, pageToken` are used as the query parameters. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.
- At GET method, `contentType` is not required.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
var query = "('GoogleDriveFolderKey01' in parents or 'GoogleDriveFolderKey02' in parents) and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"

var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files'  // Modified
var options = {  // Modified
  'method'     : 'get',
  'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
};
url += `?corpora=domain&q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}&spaces=drive&pageSize=100&pageToken=${pageToken}`;  // Added

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var resultParsed = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
files = resultParsed.files
pageToken = resultParsed.pageToken
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that `service.getAccessToken()` can be used for using the method of "Files: list" in Drive API v3.
- If an error occurs please remove `corpora=domain` from the URL like below and test it again.

  ```
  url += `?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}&spaces=drive&pageSize=100&pageToken=${pageToken}`;
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: Thank you! The problem seems to be 'corpus' and 'space'.

Comment: @C02 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.